# Unable to re-install Java on Mac, error "Error: dl failure on line 560"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm having an issue re-installing Java on my Mac. I'm using a MacBook Air version 10.11.6, so the latest Java I could install on my Mac is JDK 11.
At first, I successfully installed Java 11 on my computer. I'm also using IntelliJ for Java programming, using Oracle JDK 11. Everything was fine. But then, I had an assignment that required Java 17, so I downloaded it inside IntelliJ. It worked fine for a few days, then it crashed. [The issue inside IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8pS8.png) this is the error in IntelliJ when I tried to used Java 17 inside IntelliJ.
To troubleshoot the problems, I uninstalled everything: all Java versions on my Mac and IntelliJ, then re-installed everything again but I still couldn't use Java 17 inside IntelliJ, so I settled with Java 11 for now.
However, when I checked java version on my Mac, I received the same error

> Error: dl failure on line 560
> Error: failed /Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
> Referenced from: /Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> in /Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib

even though I have removed Java 17 and re-installed Java 11. I also re-installed JRE, the latest version. Now I can't run Java from my terminal.
I asked my professor and other experienced classmates but they didn't have the answers yet. Hopefully someone here could help me.
Thank you.

Comment: “ re-installed Java 11. I also re-installed JRE,” ?? If you installed a JDK, you have no need for a JRE.

Comment: You seem to be working too hard. I suggest you delete everything in /Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ and in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/. Then start fresh with an installer from your choice of vendor: Amazon, Azul Systems, Adoptium, BellSoft, Pivotal, Oracle, SAP, Red Hat/IBM, etc. Be sure to get installer for macOS, for Intel x86 chip. Install *one* JDK, not JRE. Then install [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) to add an icon menu to your menu bar. Use that menu to auto-install IntelliJ.

Comment: Actually, later versions of IntelliJ will download and install your choice of JDK for you.  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/download-jdk/

Comment: I know JRE may not be needed but I ran out of options, so I tried it anyway. Thank you so much for your help, I was able to fix it. What was wrong is that I didn't pay attention to the /Users/Truc/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ folder. I just deleted all of it, then the re-installing worked. Thank you.

Comment: I have a follow up question, appreciate it if you can answer. Downloading a jdk inside IntelliJ is not the same as installling that JDK on your computer, right? Thanks.